# Childfragment background color (magically) changed

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

**TL;DR** Within a `ViewPager`, I have a `Fragment` with two child fragments, when I change the background color of list in one child fragment, it sometimes also change the background color of the other child fragment.

So, I have `ViewPager` with 2 fragments, fragment 1 (`FragmentOne`) has 2 child fragment, `FragmentOneA` and `FragmentOneB`, fragment 2 is `FragmentTwo`.

`FragmentOneA` is just a `Fragment` and `FragmentOneB` is a `ListFragment`.

In `FragmentOneB`, I set color between odd row and even row. Odd row is yellow, even row just white.

So within the `ViewPager`, the fragment I show first in `FragmentOne` is `FragmentOneA`, then I pressed button in `FragmentOneA` to replace that fragment with `FragmentOneB`.

**This happened:**

1) I pressed button in `FragmentOneA` to replace it with `FragmentOneB`. Then I pressed Back button to pop the stack. I did that few times.

2) At sometime, the background color in `FragmentOneA` was changed to yellow. And then I did number 1) again and at some time, the background was changed back to white.

**I just don't understand why this happened.**

Image of `FragmentOneA` before event 1) with white background:

[image: FragmentOneA]

Image of `FragmentOneB` that's shown after I click that blue button "Cari penerbangan":

[image: FragmentOneB]

Image of `FragmentOneA` after I did event number 1) a few times:

[image: FragmentOneA wrong]

**The code of `Activity` that holds the `ViewPager`:**

```
public class MyActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    private static final int NUM_PAGES = 2;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private PagerAdapter adapter;
    private FragmentManager fragmentManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

        adapter = new PagerAdapter(fragmentManager);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        Fragment fragment = (Fragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("android:switcher:" + R.id.pager + ":"viewPager.getCurrentItem());

        if (fragment != null) { // could be null if not instantiated yet
            if (fragment.getView() != null) {
                // Pop the backstack on the ChildManager if there is any. If
                // not, close this activity as normal.
                if (!fragment.getChildFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate()) {
                    finish();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position) {
            case 0:
                FragmentOne d = new FragmentOne();
                return d;
            case 1:
                return new FragmentTwo();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return NUM_PAGES;
        }
    }
}
```

**The code of `FragmentOne`:**

```
public class FragmentOne extends Fragment {
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    FrameLayout root = new FrameLayout(getActivity());
    root.setId(R.id.layout_root);

    FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.add(R.id.layout_root, new FragmentOneA());
    transaction.commit();

    return root;
}
```

}

**The code of `FragmentOneA` when the blue button get clicked:**

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = getParentFragment().getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
transaction.replace(R.id.layout_root, new FragmentOneB());
transaction.commit();
```

**Long post, but I've reviewed my code many times, so if you know anything please give me some answers. Many thanks for you..**

My point is, I just want to use odd-even row color, but somehow that affects my other fragment.

Comment: Do you use common layouts somehow? Is the id `R.id.layout_root` unique(like declared in ids.xm) or is declared in (one of) the layouts for second nested fragment? If it's declared in other layouts did you tried using an arbitrary value like 1000? Are you setting the odd/even colors in code or directly in the row layouts?

Comment: I reserve `R.id.layout_root` in the `ids.xml`. I set the list item color in code like `if (pos % 2 == 0) color=yellow; else color = white;`. Do i need to set the fragment id?

Comment: IT'S GONE. I don't know how, the backgrounds aren't compromised anymore. I didn't do a thing, but the pictures are the evidence that I wasn't dreaming. To make sure, I just need to give every view an XML ID now.